# How to make this with out using border and width: 0. I am trying to set its width by percentage for device flexibility

Tags: html, css, frontend

```
.background
{
     border-top: 252px solid red;
     border-bottom: 252px solid red;
     border-left: 750px solid blue;
     border-right: 750px solid blue;
     width: 0;
}
```

is it possible to generate this shape by using percentages rather than px not using border would be a great help

Comment: Use `vw` and `vh`, some info [here](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/).

Comment: is it possible to use vw and vh for borders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linear gradient for this:

```css
body {
 height:100vh;
 margin:0;
}

.background {
  height:100%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top right,    blue 50%,red 50.2%) top,
    linear-gradient(to bottom right, blue 50%,red 50.2%) bottom;
 background-size:100% 50.1%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
.background {
     border-top: 20vh solid red;
     border-bottom: 20vh solid red;
     border-left: 100vw solid blue;
     border-right: 100vw solid blue;
     width: 0;
}
```

And the result like this: 
[image]

Comment: is there a fix for ie8 below? because i need a cross browser code. thanks